# Updating two javascript objects using simplified ES2015 destructuring syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have two objects - a local object and a global object.

```
let globalObject = {

  alpha: 'Alpha Value',
  beta: {betaGlobal1: 'Default Beta Global 1 Value'} 
};

let localObject = {

  betaLocal: 'Custom Local Beta Value', // <= May be present or absent
  gamma: 'Gamma Value'
};
```

If the local object contains the property `betaLocal`, I would like to update the corresponding `beta.betaGlobal` property in the global object. Otherwise I would like to add a `betaLocal` property to the local object which corresponds to its `beta.betaGlobal` counterpart property in the global object.

Here is where I've got to without ES2015 Destructuring:

```js
let propertyName = 'betaGlobal1';

let globalObject = {

  alpha: 'Alpha Value',
  beta: {betaGlobal1: 'Default Beta Global 1 Value'} 
};

let localObject = {

  betaLocal: 'Custom Local Beta Value', // <= May be present or absent
  gamma: 'Gamma Value'
};

// ATTEMPT FOUR
let beta = localObject.betaLocal || globalObject.beta[propertyName];
localObject.betaLocal = globalObject.beta[propertyName] = beta;

console.log(globalObject);
console.log(localObject);
```

Prior to `// ATTEMPT FOUR`, I also tried:

```
// ATTEMPT ONE
if (!localObject.hasOwnProperty('betaLocal')) {

    localObject.betaLocal = globalObject.beta[propertyName];
}

else {

  globalObject.beta[propertyName] = localObject.betaLocal;
}
```

---

```
// ATTEMPT TWO
if (!localObject.hasOwnProperty('betaLocal')) {

  localObject.betaLocal = globalObject.beta[propertyName];
}

globalObject.beta[propertyName] = localObject.betaLocal;
```

---

```
// ATTEMPT THREE
let beta = localObject.betaLocal || globalObject.beta[propertyName];
localObject.betaLocal = beta;
globalObject.beta[propertyName] = beta;
```

---

They all work, so that's great.

But what I'd **really like to do** is convey the above using ES2015+ object destructuring.

But I really can't get my head around it. Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible, but it wouldn't really improve anything. Your `ATTEMPT ONE` is by far the clearest, I'd prefer it. Your third code is assigning the same *reference* object to both, which is probably undesirable (if one of them gets mutated, the other one will as well)

Comment: I vote attempt two, although it's logically not equivalent to attempt one. In fact, attempt three isn't equivalent to either because it's coercing falsey. Only attempt four and three are equivalent, so the question is unclear. I don't see how destructuring helps at all, supporting CP above, in any event. BTW, if you do use attempt one, switch the `else` and `if` blocks and remove the negation.

Comment: This question is totally ok to ask here but I think you will get also useful feedback at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally cracked it.

It looks pretty recondite though. I don't think I'll be using it.

```js
let propertyName = 'betaGlobal1';

let globalObject = {

  alpha: 'Alpha Value',
  beta: {betaGlobal1: 'Default Beta Global 1 Value'} 
};

let localObject = {

  betaLocal: 'Custom Local Beta Value', // <= May be present or absent
  gamma: 'Gamma Value'
};

// ATTEMPT FIVE

if (localObject.hasOwnProperty('betaLocal')) {
  
  ({betaLocal: globalObject.beta.betaGlobal1} = localObject);
}

else {

  ({beta: {betaGlobal1: localObject.betaLocal}} = globalObject);
}

console.log(globalObject);
console.log(localObject);
```